# Why is my JSON parsing null when api returns value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to get the longitude and latitude for a postcode using the http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/ JSON response.

If I browse to that api + a UK postcode, it returns a JSON string. However, when I try to do this and parse it programmatically with JSON.NET C# I am getting a null and I am not sure why as it seems I followed the suggestions I have seen elsewhere on this site.

This is my code

```
string pCode = "postcode" //user entered value
            string longitude;
            string latitude;

            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                var json = wc.DownloadString("http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/" +pCode);

                dynamic data = JObject.Parse(json);

                longitude = data.longitude;
                latitude = data.latitude;
            }
```

But longitude and latitude are returning null.

Comment: If you're using `JObject` you don't need to use `dynamic`.

Comment: Inspect the JSON string?

Comment: @Dai thanks - this was how i saw it in another example here. What would I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from service response, that info is wrapped in result object:

http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/W4%201TH

To get values try something like:

```
...
longitude = data.result.longitude;
latitude = data.result.latitude;
...
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I hadn't spotted the result:{} bit. That has solved my problem, very grateful thank you. (Will accept as soon as it lets me!)